# Configuring HAProxy to reject/deny requests containing multiple HTTP headers of the same name

Tags: http-headers, conditional-statements, haproxy

I'd like to express the HAProxy condition

> the request contains more than one `Transfer-Encoding` headers

so I can deny or reject such requests. I've scanned through the [HAProxy documentation](http://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/2.4/configuration.html), but I couldn't find how to express that condition. Is it even possible?

Comment: http://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/2.4/configuration.html#7.3.6-req.hdr_cnt "it can be used to
detect presence, absence or abuse of a specific header, as well as to block
request smuggling attacks by rejecting requests which contain more than one
of certain headers"

Comment: @MichałPolitowski Oh nice! That looks like exactly what I was looking for. Care to make it an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`req.hdr_cnt`](http://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/2.4/configuration.html#7.3.6-req.hdr_cnt) or [`req.fhdr_cnt`](http://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/2.4/configuration.html#7.3.6-req.fhdr_cnt) fetches should be usable for your purpose. They return the number of occurrences of a particular request header. They differ in that `req.hdr_cnt` counts comma-separated parts of a header value as distinct headers.

```
acl too_many_headers req.fhdr_cnt(transfer-encoding) gt 1
```